# powerBi replace list text when retrieve list filed in json

Tags: rest, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, gitlab-api

I am trying to retrieve information about my project in gitlab by calling rest api in web connector in powerBi. the json that return is nested and have a list filed that named tag_list and have some values. in table that powerBi generated, the  tag_list generated but the value is a list text. how i solved the problem ?

The json is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEiXM.png)

but the result in table in powerbi is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76vqC.png)

Comment: if below answer solved you question, please toggle checkmark to accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can click the arrows atop those list columns, one by one, to expand them, or with a bit of code, expand them down together. Sample code to expand together:

```
let Source =#table({"Sample1", "Sample2","Sample3"},{{"aaaa",{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}},{"bbb",{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}},{"ccc",{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}}}),
#"Expanded Sample2" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Source, "Sample2"),
#"Expand"=Table.FromColumns(
    Table.ToColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Sample2",{"Sample3"}))
    & {Table.ExpandListColumn( Source, "Sample3")[Sample3]},
   Table.ColumnNames(Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Sample2",{"Sample3"}))&{"Sample3"}
)
in #"Expand"
```

[image]

Alternately, combine all the items into single text

```
let Source =#table({"Sample1", "Sample2","Sample3"},{{"aaaa",{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}},{"bbb",{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}},{"ccc",{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h"}}}),
part1 = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"Sample2", each Text.Combine(_,","), type text}}),
part2 = Table.TransformColumns(part1,{{"Sample3", each Text.Combine(_,","), type text}})
in  part2
```

[image]

For better help, post a full working JSON snippet in text not graphic format